# How do I implement modules using Typescript 1.5 and AngularJS 1.4?

Tags: angularjs, typescript1.5

I have an Angular 1.4 application that was written using an earlier version of Typescript.  Now I am looking to update this to use the new module capabilities that Typescript 1.5 gives me.

Does anyone have any examples of how I can implement modules with the new Typescript and current AngularJS. I have seen examples that don't use Typescript but have yet to find any example that uses Typescript that is for Angular 1.4

Comment: Do you mean Typescript modules, Angular modules, or both?

Comment: @Sander_P - I'm sorry but I am not sure.  All I know is I would like to do it in the way that makes the most sense now that we have Typescript 1.5 available. So far I have not been able to find any examples and judging from the upvotes to the question I think this is a topic that would be of interest to many people.

Comment: That's why I also upvoted it :)

Comment: Have you looked at John Papa's repository: https://github.com/johnpapa/hottowel-angular-typescript/tree/master/src/client/app

Comment: This question is currently being discussed here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302196/400654

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typescript 1.5 supports [ES6 module syntax](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules) which are de-facto standard as of now because of the ES6 being officialy released as ES2015. Typescript 1.5 rebranded internal / external modules into namespace and modules and you should be doing it using modules. I have a [github repository](https://github.com/tomastrajan/component-pattern-for-angular-js-1-x), where I am using this module import export syntax (without typescript but that doesn't matter because module import export syntax is the same). This example project was heavily inspired by reading this [tutorial](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/).

Generally speaking you also want to use some build tool (I recommend Webpack). Then you can take the code described in the links above and start adding types and interfaces and using TS classes instead of ES6 classes.

Edit: also you should use [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) for Angular JS declaration file